# Scroll down to certain position on a third-party website

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am building an Angular/Rails app now. In my FAQ page, I make `a` tag to introduce my users to more information. When the user clicks the `a` tag, I want to take my users to a certain point of the website. Is there a way to do it? If I wanna take my users to the bottom of below `a` tag, how would I do it?

```
<a href="www.reddit.com">Click here for more info!</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the article/section/div has an ID, just append that to the URL with a `#` like this:

https://www.reddit.com/#thing_t3_4ptfdr

Comment: What if the website where I want to point at does not have div Id? It seems like where I want to point at is a h3 tag.

Comment: Not possible AFAIK, sorry.

Comment: Gotcha :( Or is there a way to search certain word before I redirect my user?

Comment: usually important parts of a website *do* have an ID - just look for it using your browser's developer tools - in CMS systems these are often applied dynamically

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately, this website has one div which contains 20 different `p tag` and I need to point at one of them. It seems like there's no way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a reference in the target page to scroll to. Search for Div id's.

If the div in target page is something like this;

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  Some content
</div>
```

then your anchor tag should be like this;

```html
<a href="http://www.somedomain.com/somepage.html#myDiv">Take me there!</a>
```

This will take you directly to that div in the target page.

Hope this helps...

Comment: What if the website where I want to point at does not have div Id? It seems like where I want to point at is a h3 tag.

Comment: There is not much you can do if no identifier present in H3 :(